# Libgdx box2d Sprite positioning complex polygon

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, box2d

After my last question got answered I encountered a new problem:
It's the following, as you can see in this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXQRr.png

There you can see my Polygon that I use for my Dynamic Game Object

I MUST place this red point bottom left **round about** in the middle of this polygon..

But how can I calculate the X/Y for my Sprite??

Normally I would say

```
polygonShape.setAsBox(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

and sprite positioning is than as following:

```
sprite.position.set(body.getPosition.x - WIDTH / 2, body.getPosition.y - HEIGHT / 2
```

but this is now impossible with this polygon, because the body phyiscs editor places the origin of body normally on X,Y 0 and the vertices in upper right as you can see in the picture posted above..
But in my case, the origin of the body(the red point) is placed somewhere in the middle of this polygon. (To allow correct rotation)

How am I supposed to calculate the correct X/Y point? Half width half height is NEARLY correct, still a minimal offset because: I cant place the origin PERFECTLY in the middle..

I have following math relevant points given:

- MAX/MIN X/Y from body/fixture
- WIDTH/HEIGHT from body/fixture
- origin from body

I just cant get the right equation to calculate the correct position for the sprite.. And hacking is ugly, there must be a way to get it..

I'm struggling with this problem since hours..

Question: How to calculate X,Y for sprite, when origin of body is "nearly in the middle" and **NOT** perfect in the middle ?

Answer (score 0):

I really tried so much..
Maybe I should not try to invent the wheel again.. "dermetfan" had already developed some really epic utils for Libgdx.
As example "Box2dSprite"

```
box2dsprite.draw(batch, body)
```

rotation etc. is done by the class.

I just can say.. epic :)

If you have the same problem, I can say, you should give it a try!

https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils/wiki/browse/

Here you can see all his classes.